# How to handle call ended event with Agora UIKit and Flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

When hitting the end call button (the red one), I am getting this error:
I need to understand How to handle call ended event with Agora UIKit and Flutter

[How to handle call ended event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJs1Q.png)

```
  bool _debugAssertNotDisposed() {
    assert(() {
      if (_debugDisposed) {
        throw FlutterError(
          'A $runtimeType was used after being disposed.\n'
          'Once you have called dispose() on a $runtimeType, it can no longer be used.',
        );
      }
      return true;
    }());
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are eventHandlers for everything that agora does. Specifically there is a `leaveChannel` handler, in that handler you can go to a specific view or page.

Or you can have the video call in a specific page, and then you don't do anything and it returns to the previous page

#### Update:

*Please use the latest version of the Flutter UIKit ([v1.0.0](http://pub.dev/packages/agora_uikit)) which fixes the `endCall` error.*

Comment: Just to add to the above answer, please use the latest version of the UIKit ([v1.0.0](http://pub.dev/packages/agora_uikit)) which fixes the `endCall` error.

Answer (score 0):

AgoraClient client = AgoraClient(
agoraEventHandlers: AgoraRtcEventHandlers(
leaveChannel: (state) => Navigator.pop(context))),